# Stack spacing is ignored

Tags: ios, autolayout

I've an image which is downloaded async. This image is resized to fit the screen by a constraint. This seems to break the vertical spacing between the image and label in the table cell which is set by the stack view.

**Table view**

[image: Table view]

**xCode constrains**

[image]

**Result iPhone 5S**

[image: Result iPhone 5S]

**Code to set the image height:**

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "overview", for: indexPath) as! OverviewCell

    let upload = images[indexPath.row]

    cell.titleLabel.text = upload.image.title

    let cachedImage = cachedImages[upload.image.imageUrl]

    if let cachedImage = cachedImage {
        var cellFrame = cell.frame.size
        cellFrame.width = cellFrame.width - 30

        let resizedImage = cachedImage.resize(width: cellFrame.width)

        cell.imageView!.image = resizedImage

        cell.heightConstrain.constant = resizedImage.size.height
    }
    else {

        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            let data = try! Data.init(contentsOf: URL.init(string: upload.image.imageUrl)!)

            DispatchQueue.main.sync {
                self.cachedImages[upload.image.imageUrl] = UIImage.init(data:data)!

                self.tableView.beginUpdates()
                self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.fade)
                self.tableView.endUpdates()

            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: In interface builder properties for the image view. Tick “clips to bounds”

Comment: @Fogmeister Doesn't seem to make a difference

Comment: try out changing the `distribution` property of the `stackView`

Comment: @JožeWs I tried every possible distribution option. But they all have the same result except the fill equally which creates a huge gap on the top and bottom.

Comment: Hmm... why are you setting a height constraint on the cell?

Comment: Don’t put a height constraint on the cell. The cells height should be determined by the height of the content. The image view plus the label plus the spacing in the stack view and any margin around the stack view. Don’t mess around with that. So just remove the height constraint from the cell. Also... what are you returning (or setting) for the tables row height?

Comment: @Fogmeister The height constraint is on the UIImage. If I don't do this the UIImage takes up all the height. estimatedRowHeight = 200, rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

Comment: Are you sure the spacing is set to what you want? Have to logged out the spacing when setting a breakpoint or something? Unless you are not including something here then it should work. I can’t see anything in the code you have supplied that is broken. Maybe if I could see more of the project?!

Comment: @Fogmeister Here's the repo: https://github.com/Jamiek94/Motoren-iOS. The overview group contains the items you are probably interested in. It should function properly with firebase. It's all beta, so you can mess around if you like.

Comment: Hmm... having a quick look it looks like everything is fine. I’m really not sure what’s going on with it. Only had a look on my phone so may have a look on my laptop but I can’t see anything that would cause your problem.

Comment: That makes two of us, haha. Thanks for taking a look!